# What is the best way to incorporate troubleshooting steps in an answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

In the question ["Chain slipping off derailleur jockey (need suggestions ASAP)"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8987/chain-slipping-off-derailleur-jockey-need-suggestions-asap) the initial question put @DanielRHicks and I off in the wrong direction, because of an assumption made from the phrasing of the question.

Because of that, [my answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/8988/1259)'s initial response was focused on the wrong possible solution.

In the comments, Stephen responded, and we were able to work out the correct issue and solution.

I wanted to include that information in the answer without eliminating the initial incorrect assumption, since it still might be valid for someone else, and provide the steps we took to come to that conclusion, so that others could follow it even if they had a different reason for the same problem.

I deleted the comments section to clean up the page, and used the numbered list to show our comments (and troubleshooting steps) in order.

My question here is, is there a better way to ensure the right answer is in the answer, without eliminating the steps to get there?